# Размер блока мод мобильный телефон

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Добрый день,подскажите,как долее адаптивно и лучше сделать.Нужно задать размер блоку,который хороши бы отображался на мобильных.
например задать div фиксировано ширину `1000 px`
или же использовать `max-width` и `процентами` задать.Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да хоть 2000. По умолчанию на мобиле этот блок будет пропорционально уменьшен так, чтобы влазить в экран.

Answer (score 2):

Как писал [@IonDen](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/181240/ionden), блок будет уменьшен соответственно экрану, но и все его содержимое будет так же уменьшено. Поэтому, если не оптимизировать блок под маленький экран, пользователю может понадобиться использовать приближение, чтобы рассмотреть содержимое блока, что неудобно.

Адаптивная верстка подразумевает использование `media-queries + %`.